# Blurry labels in GeoGraphics

Tags: labeling, geography, geographics, rasterize

I want to keep the same GeoZoomLevel, but increase the resolution of the labels. I'm struggling to control that:

```
GeoGraphics[{Green, Polygon@Entity["Country", "Greenland"]}, 
 GeoRange -> "World", GeoProjection -> "Equirectangular", 
 GeoZoomLevel -> 1, ImageSize -> 1100, GeoResolution -> 4, 
 RasterSize -> 900]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use background without labels (with the option `GeoBackground -> GeoStyling["StreetMapNoLabels"]`) and add the labels as `Text` primitives:

```
oceanlabels = Text[Style[StringRiffle[StringSplit[ToUpperCase@#["Name"]], "\n"], 
      24, Gray, Italic, ShowStringCharacters -> False], 
     GeoGridPosition[GeoPosition[#["CenterCoordinates"]], "Equirectangular"]] & /@ 
  (Entity["Ocean", #] & /@ {"PacificOcean", "AtlanticOcean", "IndianOcean"});

continentlabels = Text[Style[StringRiffle[StringSplit[ToUpperCase@#["Name"]], "\n"], 
      24, Gray, Bold, ShowStringCharacters -> False], 
     GeoGridPosition[GeoPosition[#["CenterCoordinates"]], "Equirectangular"]] & /@ 
   Most[EntityList["GeographicRegion"]];

GeoGraphics[{Green, Polygon@Entity["Country", "Greenland"], oceanlabels, continentlabels}, 
 GeoRange -> "World", GeoProjection -> "Equirectangular", 
 GeoZoomLevel -> 1, ImageSize -> 1100,
 GeoBackground -> GeoStyling["StreetMapNoLabels"]]
```

[image]